# Filenames that contain a specific string copy the content and add a column with specific value based on the found string

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following problem. 
I have like 20K xlsx files and want to put them into one workingsheet, which is working quite well right now.

Each xlsx file has a specific string.

For instance:

- Test_a_LME.xlsx
- Test_a_KZE.xlsx
- Test_b_LME.xlsx
- Test_a_KZE.xlsx

and so on..

What I want now is that I add a string (Range until the lastrow of data in each file) based on the ending of the file (LME & KZE) (Please see the picture)

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
Sub XlsMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Dim myFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Change folder path of excel files here
Set dirObj = mergeObj.getfolder("Folder")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

For Each everyObj In filesObj
    Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

    bookList.Activate
    Range("A4:A" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)

    bookList.Activate
    Range("D4:E" & Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)

    bookList.Activate
    Range("B4:B" & Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Range("F65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)

Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

I am pretty sure that I need to add probably an if statement into the for loop but I dont know exactly how this could look like.

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: Would you expect the A,B and D columns to contain the same number of rows?  Seems like if one of those was different from the others then that might cause your compiled data to become mis-aligned.

Comment: @TimWilliams A, B and D will always have the exact number of rows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub XlsMerger()
    Dim bookList As Workbook, fldr As Object
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
    Dim myFile As String, lastRow As Long, wsTarget As Worksheet, rwTarget As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Change folder path of excel files here
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.getfolder("Folder")
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set rwTarget = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

    For Each everyObj In filesObj

        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

        With bookList.Sheets(1)
            'find last row using ColA
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            'then use that same last row value to copy the 3 columns
            .Range("A4:A" & lastRow).Copy
            rwTarget.Columns("A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

            .Range("D4:D" & lastRow).Copy
            rwTarget.Columns("D").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

            .Range("B4:B" & lastRow).Copy
            rwTarget.Columns("F").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

            'fill in the filename info: make adjustments here as needed
            rwTarget.Columns("B").Resize(lastRow - 3, 1).Value = bookList.Name

        End With

        Set rwTarget = rwTarget.Offset(lastRow - 3, 0) 'offset for next paste

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        bookList.Close
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the position of the **LAST** underscore in the filename, then get the three **MIDDLE** characters of that filename string, starting one character past the underscore.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim fn As String
    fn = "Test_a_LME.xlsx"
    Dim pos1 As Long
    pos1 = InStrRev(fn, "_") + 1
    Debug.Print Mid$(fn, pos1, 3)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem which is way more bothering is to fill the cells ones I determined the name of the file.